# NginX allow only internal IP on a specific URL

Tags: nginx, server, config, ip-address, mautic

I have a location block in my NginX config that looks like this:

```
location /s/login {
allow 192.168.5.0/24;
deny all;
}
```

But this only works partially. With external IP they get a 403 error, which is correct, but on internal IP like 192.168.5.41, I get a 404 error. But I'd like to see the site. 
The whole config file look like this:

```
  8 server {
  9         listen *:443 ssl;
 10         server_name news.example.com;
 11
 12         root /var/www/test;
 13
 14         index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
 15
 16         location / {
 17                 # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
 18                 try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
 19         }
 20
 21         location ~ \.php$ {
 22                 include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
 23                 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
 24         }
 25
 26         location ~* ^/index.php {
 27                 # try_files $uri =404;
 28                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
 29                 # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
 30
 31                 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
 32                 fastcgi_index index.php;
 33                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 34
 35                 include fastcgi_params;
 36
 37                 fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
 38                 fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
 39                 fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
 40                 fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
 41         }
 42
 43         location /s/login {
 44                 allow 192.168.5.0/24;
 45                 deny all;
 46         }
 47
 48         # Remove 'index.php' from the URL
```

EDIT:
The access.log entries for internal IPs looks like this:

```
192.168.5.41 - - [21/Jun/2018:08:13:59 +0200] "GET /s/login HTTP/1.1" 404 152 "https://news.example.com/s/contacts" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
```

And for external IPs like this:

```
178.197.230.117 - - [21/Jun/2018:08:21:59 +0200] "GET /s/login HTTP/1.1" 403 152 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Android 7.1.1; Mobile; rv:60.0) Gecko/60.0 Firefox/60.0"
```

In error.log there are lots of entries like this:

```
2018/06/21 08:35:12 [error] 52154#52154: *1 open() "/var/www/mautic/s/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.5.41, server: news.example.com, request: "GET /s/login HTTP/1.1", host: "news.example.com"
```

Well as you can see, I hadn't had a look at the log files. Due to the entries in the error.log, it's clear what I did wrong and why I got 404 errors.

Comment: what's in access.log and error.log at that point?

Comment: Thanks @AlexC for reminding me to look at the log files.